# Is this the right way to store the residuals from an OLS regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, economics

I wanted to simulate 1000 iterations of an OLS regression and save the residuals in a n x 1  vector.

For doing so, this is the code that I came up with:

```
Data <- read.csv("cons.csv")

ols <- function(y,x){
  ones <- rep(1,length(x))
  X = matrix(c(ones, x), ncol = 2)
  beta = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% as.matrix(y)
  return(beta)
}

b0 = 0.42
b1 = 0.95
n = 198
x = log(Data$di[-199])
xT = log(Data$di[199])

beta <- matrix(0, 2, 1000)

for (i in 1:1000) {
  set.seed(i) 
  u <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
  y <- b0 + b1 * x + u
  beta[, i] <- ols(y, x) 
  residuals <- y - (beta[1,i] + beta[2,i] * x)
}
```

Is this the right way to calculate the residuals or am I missing something here?

Comment: Simply use the `lm` function which fit a model using OLS. And then you can get the residuals. For example: `fit <- lm(...)` & `residuals <- fit$residuals`.

Comment: @AdrienRiaux unfortunately, my advisor wants me to use the `ols` function as defined above. With that in mind, would my code work as expected?

Comment: You are overwriting `residuals` with each pass through your `for` loop, this is likely not what you want/need. Perhaps you need to define `residuals <- matrix(nrow = n, ncol = 1000)` before the loop, then fill it with `residuals[,i] <- y - (...)`

Comment: @r2evans I initialised it as `residuals <- matrix(0, 198, 1)` as I need a 198x1 vector. After that, I just changed the code to `residuals[i] <- y - (beta[1,i] + beta[2,i] * x)` within the loop. Does this look fine now?

Comment: Perhaps we have a different idea of what "residuals" are supposed to be. I'm thinking it'd be a vector length-`n` for each iteration in the `for` loop, but it sounds like you want it reduced to length-1. How is that exactly?